# Is there an easy way to parse an HTML document and remove everything except a particular table?

Tags: java, c++, python, html, parsing

I'm trying to patch together a quick utility that will read records from a website's table and insert them into a database. There are a few conditions:

1. The page's source is *messy*. Lots of CSS and Javascript thrown about. (It's an internal site.)
2. I know the ID of the table I want.
3. Once I have the table, I have to parse the rows further to get the specific informtation I'm looking for.
4. This has to be done server-side. (Preferably java, python, or C++, although if there is another particularly good option, that's fine too.)

So does anyone know of a good library or utility that can "grab" an html element by ID and let me parse it? I know it goes without saying, but I'd prefer one that's as quick as possible.

Comment: Javascript: `getElemenetById()` or jQuery: `$('#elementId').html()`

Comment: What language are you wanting to use?

Comment: @alfasin thanks, I will give Javascript a try -- is this the fastest method to use, performance wise?

Comment: @MikeBrant The language is not too important to me -- whatever has the best performance/library for a situation like this.

Comment: @user1209326 it all depends on what you're planning to do with the data. If it involves only client-side then there shouldn't be much difference between using JS and jQuery, but if you need some kind of server-side manipulation (meaning Ajax or some additional component that will interact with the server) - then it's a different story and you might want to use some DOM parsing library in the language that you're using.

Comment: @alfasin Actually, I'd prefer this to be done server-side. Does this change anything besides that I'd need a DOM parsing library instead? (Sorry, I don't usually do web dev, but my partner and I are hacking together a utility to automate some of our work)

Comment: Like @MikeBrant said, the answer that you're looking for depends on the language you plan on using. Please add the Language to the question and also add a relevant tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de) in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from lxml import html # $ apt-get install python-lxml or $ pip install lxml

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/q/11939631')
doc = html.parse(page).getroot()

div = doc.get_element_by_id('question')
for tr in div.find('table').iterchildren('tr'):
    for td in tr.iterchildren('td'):
        print(td.text_content()) # process td
```

If you are familiar with jQuery; you could use [pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/index.html). It adds jQuery interface on top of lxml:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyquery import PyQuery # $ apt-get install python-pyquery or
                            # $ pip install pyquery

# d is like the $ in jquery
d = PyQuery(url='http://stackoverflow.com/q/11939631', parser='html')
for tr in d("#question table > tr"):
    for td in tr.iterchildren('td'):
        print(td.text_content())
```

Though in this case `pyquery` doesn't add enough. Here's the same using only `lxml`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from lxml import html

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/q/11939631')
doc = html.parse(page).getroot()
for tr in doc.cssselect('#question table > tr'):
    for td in tr.iterchildren('td'):
        print(td.text_content()) # process td
```

Note: the last two examples enumerate rows in *all* tables (not just the first one) inside `#question` element.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can select an element by it's Id.

See [use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables](http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/)

The gist of the article is:

```
var tableObject = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function(i) {
  var row = {};

  // Find all of the table cells on this row.
  $(this).find('td').each(function(i) { //do something with each td }
```

Comment: Yep. In an edit 90 mins after I posted. The old psychic powers are a bit low today...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
<table[^>]*id="whatever"[^>]*>(.*?)</table>
```

Then extract the first group (the part of the match in parens) and parse out the rows:

```
<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>
```

Finally, with each row, extract the cells:

```
<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>
```

This would work in any of the languages you mentioned.

Comment: This is the approach i'd take as well off the top of my head. Its a shame you can't do this with jQuery client side and just pass the data over though. Its a much simpler approach that regex.